# when disabling a button in a table in angular the next row button changes as the length of the array changes

Tags: angular

I have a problem with disabling a button in a mat table in angular. Each row has a button to cancel a jenkins job. I have two lists: one of pending builds in which I can press the button to cancel the job, and the one of builds where the canceled jobs appear when canceled. The problem is that with this code, when I press the button of the second in the list, the third, pass to have that index value, in the array, and get the disabled to true, as the other one disappears from the array.

1- button enabled
2- button enabled
3- button enabled

I press the 2 button

New scenario:

1- button enabled
2- button disabled
3- button enabled

after a few seconds when the row 2 disappear from this list number 3 gets the index 2 and disables the button even though not pressed

1- button enabled
***2- button disabled*** it disappear
3- button disabled even when not pressed

My code:

html:

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="buildId">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Cancel </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i=index">
          <button mat-flat-button color="accent" [disabled]="clicked[i]"
            (click)="cancelBuildingImage(element.buildId); clicked[i] = true">
            Cancel Build
          </button>
        </td>
</ng-container>
```

my . ts

```
constructor(private builderService: BuilderService, private snackMessageService: SnackMessageService) {
    this.buildingImageList = new Array();
    this.callLoop = setInterval(() => { this.populateBuildingImageList() }, 15000);
    this.clicked = []
  }

ngOnInit() {
    this.populateBuildingImageList();
    this.buildingImageList.forEach(el => {
      this.clicked.push(false);
    });
  }
```

any ideas how can i fix it?

Comment: Can you share a Stackblitz example?

Comment: I can't sorry, this works with a jenkins in back and I can't reproduce it with a stackblitz

Comment: The problem is that when I cancel it disappears from the list to put it in another list, and the superior row gets the index from the one before changing the button to disabled even when not desired